# Upload image to server from iOS device

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to upload an image on a remote server. If i download images on my phone from google and upload them e.g http://www.mangauk.com/gallery/albums/album-11/lg/scooby.jpeg it uploads just fine. However if i try to upload images that i have taken with the camera, it does not work. The server just hangs.

```
(IBAction)uploadImage {
    /*
     turning the image into a NSData object
     getting the image back out of the UIImageView
     setting the quality to 90
    */
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, 90);
    // setting up the URL to post to
    NSString *urlString = @"http://iphone.zcentric.com/test-upload.php";

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    /*
     add some header info now
     we always need a boundary when we post a file
     also we need to set the content type

     You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same 
     as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
    */
    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the post
    */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="ipodfile.jpg"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-streamrnrn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"rn--%@--rn",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);
}
```

and php script

```
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://iphone.zcentric.com/uploads/{$file}";
}
```

Comment: How should anybody be able to help you without being able to review your code?

Comment: can you please put code here?

Comment: use your senses, @vikingosegundo, use your extra senses... ))) no one reads the FAQ before posting questions...

Comment: Ok sorry, i have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @SavaMazăre This has nothing to do with faqs. It is just simple logic, that one needs to show code if he wants it to be corrected.

Comment: Ok, @RoryLester, we've got the code, but tell us also: you said Scooby gets uploaded, but your taken with camera image doesn't? and you use the same above code to upload it, correct?

Comment: is this line `[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="ipodfile.jpg"rn"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
` working? I think, it shouldnt compile at all, as the `"` arent escaped.

Comment: The scooby image or images that i save on my phone from the internet seem to get uploaded however if i take a photo with my camera and then attempt to upload it, it does not get uploaded. The server just hangs which is why i am confused. Also yes i am using the code above to upload. Also yes, everything compiles, the code above works but i dont understand why i can only upload images that i save on my phone from the internet and not the camera.

Comment: that line can't compile, but let's assume, you are escaping and the `"` looks like `\"`. please check a) that image.image isnt nil and b) that you call of `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` returns an object and not nil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem must be in your php script since the file must be getting sent to it.

You should be defining the name of the file in your php, rather than trusting the original file name.

Otherwise someone could upload a malicious .php file and your script would happily upload it and name it .php and they could take over your server.

You should be doing something like this:

```
$uploaddir = './uploads/';
$file = $uploaddir . 'filename_chosen_by_you.jpg';
```

This will likely also solve the jpeg / jpg problem becasue you're doing the naming.

One other thing- you're also doing a synchronous request- meaning your app will just wait and freeze while doing the request (which could be a few seconds if its a big file), have a look at doing an asynchronous request. That means it will upload the image in the background and then call a function when finished, so you can tell the user everything's uploaded OK.